# How to access nodejs application installed on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I have AWS EC2 with Ubuntu instance. I successfully setup ssh access and I am able to login via ssh console. I installed NodeJS and one simple NodeJS application. 
Successfully start it by `node server.js` and when executing `curl http://localhost:8080` I can confirm application is up and running. My only issue is that I am not able to access it using provided public IP by AWS.

I can see my public IP from AWS console, and I thought it should be enough to type:
`http://aws-public-ip:8080` and it should load the application. It seams I am wrong since I don't obtain access to my app.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer by myself - I had to edit security group rule and just add rule for corresponding port. By default security group created when you create your instance has only one incoming rule for port 22.